# Serving HTML content with GAE JAVA

Tags: google-app-engine, jersey, velocity

I am using GAE with Jersey for doing RESTful services. What would be recommended way to serve HTML content. I tried JSP and  HttpServlet with Velocity. Found velocity with Servlet to be good for my requirements. But since I am using Jersey I wonder if shall use serve Velocity templates through jersey?

Or maybe somebody made a different choice and could share their experience. Thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://diary.makkiato.de/2010/04/03/using-velocity-templates-with-jersey/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jersey doesn't really have any sort of HTML templating solution built in, it's not really meant for that but it's very good as an Ajax service backend. Velocity or just plain old jsp pages are good choices for serving your HTML content. The link peter gave above is a good example of how the two can work together. You can also use jersey as a controller layer and forward responses to your jsp pages.